# Can numpy help me quickly find the index of an array, at which its sum is negativ for the first time?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do something like this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1000)
a -= .55
a[0] = 1
b = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    b += a[i]
    if b < 0:
        print(i)
        break
```

a lot, and preferably it should be swift. Can NumPy help me with that? I understand that NumPy is built for vector calculation and not for this. Still, it can calculate the sum of an array blazingly fast - can I give it this specific condition (the sum is negative for the first time) to stop and tell me the index number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [`numpy.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). First, compute the cumulative sum of the elements. Then return `True/False` that `elements < 0` and return the first index that is True for `element < 0` with `argmax()`.

```
>>> (a.cumsum() < 0).argmax()
```

check both codes:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1000)
a -= .55
a[0] = 1

def check_1(a):
    b = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b += a[i]
        if b < 0:
            print(i)
            break
            
def check_2(a):
    return (a.cumsum() < 0).argmax()
```

Output: *(Generate base random input)*

```
>>> check_1(a)
6

>>> check_2(a)
6
```

Comment: could you add a timeit() performance comparison, perhaps? @imahdi

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei, you can check time like this : `%timeit check_1(a)` or `%timeit check_2(a)` in jupyter. for `np.random.rand(1000)` I got `6.81 µs ± 628 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` for both but for larger array your code is running faster.

Comment: @imahdi, with tweaking the numbers a little to make the index bigger, at which the underrun occurs, NumPy begins to shine. Thank you for introducing me to cumsum. Unfortunately this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei, no problem, can you say what you are looking for?!

Comment: @imahdi I am looking for a way to compute this at a consistently superior speed. If NumPy had a way of aborting its loop when reaching zero, that would be the case, I am sure.